# Firefox - how to window.open exactly in new tab (not in new window)

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I try to do (Angular code)

```
    var tab = window;
    if (tab != undefined) {
      tab.document.title = "RandomName";
      tab.open('data:application/json;charset=UTF-8,' + JSON.stringify(result), 'NewTab');
      tab.focus();
    };
```

And receive two issues - new windows opening in new Firefox exemplar, not in new tab.
And second issue - page Title is absent.

Comment: You can not control it

Comment: are you sure? it's a pity

Comment: tab.open('data:application/json;charset=UTF-8,' + JSON.stringify(result), '_blank');
it should work.

Comment: @Trouble, yes it work, but it less than I want. I want add title of new page and exactly new tab instead new window